# Show that the function $u(x)=1 \in W^{m,\ 2}(\Omega)$, but not in $W_0^{m,\ 2}(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have a problem:

> For $\Omega$ be a domain in $\Bbb R^n$. Show that the function $u(x)=1 \in W^{m,\ 2}(\Omega)$, but not in $W_0^{m,\ 2}(\Omega)$, for all $m \ge 1$.

=============================

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If $\Omega$ is compact then $W$ and $W_0$ coincide so your statement obviously doesn't hold. Could you correct the problem? Are we perhaps assuming $\Omega$ is open?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I'm sorry!

Comment: I fixed it. Can you help me? **Marek**

Comment: Also note that it does not hold in the case $m = 0$, since $W^{0,2}(\Omega) = L^2(\Omega) = W_0^{0,2}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thanks **gerw**, I'll update it. When we say about $W_0^{m,\ p}(\Omega)$ then we need $0 \le |\alpha| \le  m$, but can you send to me the link which has your result. ($W_0^{0,\ 2}(\Omega) \equiv W^{0,\ 2}(\Omega)$). Because this is the first time I've heard. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would like to answer the first comment : It is only if you take the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ that this two spaces coincide not at all for bounded domain.

For the problem : I will do it on $\mathbb{R}$ and $m=1$ and $\Omega=(0,1)$ (easy to adapt). To show that $u$ belongs to $W^{m,2}(\Omega)$ you only need to show that the integration by parts formula (against function in $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\Omega)$) holds. Or just notice that $u\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ theferore the classic (then the weak) derivatives exist and are $0$.

Now $W^{m,2}_0(\Omega)$ is by definition the closure of $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\Omega)$ with respect to the norm of $W^{m,2}(\Omega)$ :
$$\|\phi\|_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}=\int|\phi|^2+\int|\phi^{\prime}|^2.$$

Now assume that $u$ belongs to $W^{m,2}_0(\Omega)$ then there exists a sequence $\phi_n$ in $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\Omega)$ such that. $\|\phi_n-u\|_{W^{2,1}(\Omega)}\rightarrow 0$ which by definition imply the followings
$$\int|\phi_n-1|^2\rightarrow 0\\ \int|\phi_n^{\prime}|^2\rightarrow 0\\
\phi_n(0)=\phi_n(1)=0$$ and   integration by 
parts of the quantity $\int(\phi_n-1)$ leads easily to a contradiction. Generally the only constant function which belongs to this space is $0$.

Roughly speaking $W^{m,2}_0(\Omega)$ are functions (with appropriate weak derivatives)  which vanishes in some sense at the boundary (rigorously the trace sense) and this is not the case for $u=1$.

Note : if you are already familiar with the boundary trace of function in sobolev spaces it is obvious : $W^{m,p}_0(\Omega)$ are the function of $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ for which the trace at the boundary is 0. But since $u$ is continuous the trace of $u$ on $\partial\Omega$ is only $u_{|_{\partial\Omega}}=1\neq 0$ 
and it is over.

Comment: I said they coincide when $\Omega$ is compact. I then realized that people sometimes use the word domain to imply open, so in this case you're right of course.

Comment: ah ok. When I see domain I read open and connected  but I may be  wrong.

Comment: Anyway, +1, nice answer.

Comment: Wow! It's great, thanks **user42070**!

Comment: I use **Hölder's inequality**:
$$\int_{\Omega}(\phi_n -1) \rm dx \le \left(\int_{\Omega}|\phi_n -1|^2 \rm dx \right)^{1/2} \cdot \left( \int_{\Omega}1^2 \rm dx \right)^{1/2}$$ We take $x=0$ then LHS to $−1$ while RHS to $0$. Is it true? Anyway, I think that you have a typo :) , maybe! $$\|\phi\|_{W^{1,2}}^{2}(\Omega)=\int|\phi|^2 dx+\int|\phi^{\prime}|^2dx$$.

Comment: you are right about the typo I corrected it. Then as you said we have by holder that $\int_\Omega(\phi_n-1)\rightarrow 0$. Now I don't really get what you mean by "taking $x=0$", but if you integrate by parts this quantity you easily have that $$ \int(\phi_n-1)\cdot1=-\int\left(\phi^\prime_n(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)dx-1$$ where I took $x-\frac{1}{2}$as a primitive of 1 for nicer symetry. In the last formula you can show as well with holder that the second integral $\int\phi^\prime_n(x-\frac{1}{2})$ goes to $0$, and you have the contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand Why do you have $$\int(\phi_n-1)\cdot1=-\int\phi^\prime_n \left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)dx-1$$??? Plz, can you write more clearly?

Comment: So by integration by parts we have $$\int_0^1(\phi_n-1)\cdot1 dx=-\int(\phi_n-1)^{\prime}\cdot(x-\frac{1}{2})dx+[(\phi_n-1)\cdot(x-\frac{1}{2})]_0^1$$ don't forget that $\phi_n(0)=\phi_n(1)=0$  so that $[(\phi_n-1)\cdot(x-\frac{1}{2})]_0^1=-1\times(\frac{1}{2}-(-\frac{1}{2}))$.Of course this is stupid to choose $x-\frac{1}{2}$ as a primitive to $1$ and not just $x$. But I like it better for non-mathematical reason :), anyway the result is of course the same. does it help ?

Comment: It's \cdot or \times "$\cdot,\ \times$". At first, I did not understand your notation, because $\phi^\prime_n \left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right) \ne \phi^\prime_n \cdot \left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ it is multiplication (your **symbol**).:) Thanks **user42070**!

Comment: yes everthings is multiplication everywhere with or without cdot it is multiplication.

Comment: Yes, when I read you wrote $$\phi^\prime_n \left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$, I'm stupid and I think it means $\phi^\prime_n  \circ \left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ - The resulting **composite function**. Hence, I didn't understand. Now, I see, hihi :) . And it is: $$\int_{0}^1\underset{u}{\underbrace{\left ( \phi_n-1 \right )}} \underset{dv}{\underbrace{\rm d \left ( x-\dfrac{1}{2} \right )}}=uv \mid_{0}^1-\int _{0}^1v\rm du$$ Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: any smooth function $u_n$ with compact support approximating $1$ well will be close to $1$ on most of $\Omega$ and close to $0$ elsewhere. This implies that there will always be a region where the approximating function has a big gradient. Try to derive a contradiction by showing that the norm of $1 - u_n$ stays bounded away frow $0$ thanks to the contribution from the gradient part of the norm.

Comment: Since $$\text{supp}u_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, \ \text{if}\ x\in \Omega & \\ 
 0,\ \text{if}\ x \not \in \Omega & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ I compute the norm of $1-u_n$, then  $$\left \| u_n-u \right \|_{W^{m,2}}^2=\left \| u_n-1 \right \|_{W^{m,2}}^2=\sum_{|\alpha| \le m}\int_{\Omega}\left | D^\alpha(u_n-1) \right |^2\rm dx$$. I've understood your suggestions? **Marek**

Comment: And what do we have a contradiction? Can you add a hint, **Marek**? Thanks!